# Detecting error-control operator

Tags: php, error-handling

Please tell me if this is correct. In my error handler, I need to be able to detect when the @ error-control operator was used to suppress errors, because some external libraries (sadly) use it a lot. Execution of the script should continue, just like when you don't use custom error handlers.

When the at-sign is used, PHP temporarily sets error_reporting to 0. So at the start of a script we set error_reporting to any value but zero - we can now do some beautiful IF/ELSE magic. To avoid any errors being shown at the frontend, we also set display_errors to 0, this will override error_reporting (but we can still use it's value for magic).

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors',0);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

function error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
    if (error_reporting()===0) return;
    else die();
}

set_error_handler('error_handler');

//This issues an error, but the handler will return and execution continues.
//Remove the at-sign and the script will die()
@file();

echo 'Execution continued, hooray.';
?>
```

So.. Are there no catches here? Except the one where the external library overrides my error handling.. (any tips on that?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering what your script does, and some user notes on the [@ operator manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php), it seems what you are doing is OK.

For instance, [taras says](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php#85042) :

> I was confused as to what the @ symbol
>   actually does, and after a few
>   experiments have concluded the
>   following:
>
> - the error handler that is set gets called regardless of what level the
>     error reporting is set on, or whether
>     the statement is preceeded with @
> - it is up to the error handler to impart some meaning on the different
>     error levels. You could make your
>     custom error handler echo all errors,
>     even if error reporting is set to
>     NONE.
> - so what does the @ operator do? It temporarily sets the error reporting
>     level to 0 for that line. If that line
>     triggers an error, the error handler
>     will still be called, but it will be
>     called with an error level of 0

And the [`set_error_handler`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) manual page seems to confirm that :

> Of particular note is that this value will be 0 if the statement 
>   that caused the error was prepended by the @ error-control operator.

Here too, there are some user notes that can be useful ; for instance, [this one](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php#76900) *(see the begining of the code)*

---

Still, if what you want is to "disable" the effect of the @ operator *(not sure I understood the question correctly ; this might help you anyway)*, to be able to get the error messages while you are on your development environment, you can install the scream extension ([pecl](http://pecl.php.net/package/scream), [manual](http://php.net/scream))

Provided you configure it the right way, setting this in your php.ini (after installating/loading the extension, of course) :

```
scream.enabled = 1
```

This extension will simply disable the @ operator.

And here's an example (quoting the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/scream.examples-simple.php)) :

```
<?php
// Make sure errors will be shown
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Disable scream - this is the default and produce an error
ini_set('scream.enabled', false);
echo "Opening http://example.com/not-existing-file\n";
@fopen('http://example.com/not-existing-file', 'r');

// Now enable scream and try again
ini_set('scream.enabled', true);
echo "Opening http://example.com/not-existing-file\n";
@fopen('http://example.com/another-not-existing-file', 'r');
?>
```

And this will output :

```
Opening http://example.com/not-existing-file
Opening http://example.com/not-existing-file

Warning: fopen(http://example.com/another-not-existing-file): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in example.php on line 14
```

I am not sure I would use this extension on a production server (where I never want errors displayed), but it is very useful on a development machine, when using old code, on an application/library that uses @ operator extensivly...

Comment: +1. This confirmation was all I needed. The scream extension seems usefull, might check into that. Not in todays case though, I just want an external library to be able to do it's thing - as if my application wasn't there.